# После выполнения одного из условий elif программа всё равно выполняет else после break в цикле while

Tags: python, python-3.x

В этом коде проверяется то, какую ставку делает пользователь и выводится количество денег после ставки. Я использовал try и except чтобы ловить ошибку если пользователь введет вместо цифры букву. А если пользователь введет неизвестное число то программа по идее должна была просто выводить предупреждение и заново запускать код.

```
class BlackJack(object):
    """docstring for BlackJack"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(BlackJack, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg

    def bet(self, amount):
        self.arg -= amount
        return self.arg

cash = 2500
bet = 0

bjack = BlackJack(cash)

print('У вас',cash)
```

Следующая часть кода предположительно содержит ошибку.

```
def main():
    try:
        z = int(input('введите число для ставки\nчтобы поставить 100 нажмите 1\nчтобы поставить 200 нажмите 2\nчтобы поставить 500 нажмите 3\nчтобы поставить 1000 нажмите 4\n'))

        while True:
            if z == 1:
                bet = bjack.bet(100)
                print('\nваша ставка',cash - bet,'(ваш счет -',bet,')')
                break

            elif z == 2:
                bet = bjack.bet(200)
                print('\nваша ставка',cash - bet,'(ваш счет -',bet,')')
                break

            elif z == 3:
                bet = bjack.bet(500)
                print('\nваша ставка',cash - bet,'(ваш счет -',bet,')')
                break

            elif z == 4:
                bet = bjack.bet(1000)
                print('\nваша ставка',cash - bet,'(ваш счет -',bet,')')
                break

            else:
                print('\nВы ввели неизвестное число,\nхотя ожидалось одно из следующих цифр: 1,2,3,4\n')
                main()

    except ValueError:
        print('\nОшибка! Вы ввели букву вместо цифры!\n')
        main()
main()
```

При запуске программы через терминал программа просит ввести одно из следующих цифр: 1,2,3,4.

```
У вас 2500
введите число для ставки
чтобы поставить 100 нажмите 1
чтобы поставить 200 нажмите 2
чтобы поставить 500 нажмите 3
чтобы поставить 1000 нажмите 4
```

Специально ввожу цифру 7 и тут срабатывает ELSE

```
Вы ввели неизвестное число,
хотя ожидалось одно из следующих цифр: 1,2,3,4

введите число для ставки
чтобы поставить 100 нажмите 1
чтобы поставить 200 нажмите 2
чтобы поставить 500 нажмите 3
чтобы поставить 1000 нажмите 4
```

Потом ввожу цифру 2 и по идее программа должна выполнить вычисление и завершиться, но вместо этого программа выполняет и вычисление и потом ещё раз зачем-то запускает ELSE

```
ваша ставка 200 (ваш счет - 2300 )

Вы ввели неизвестное число,
хотя ожидалось одно из следующих цифр: 1,2,3,4

введите число для ставки
чтобы поставить 100 нажмите 1
чтобы поставить 200 нажмите 2
чтобы поставить 500 нажмите 3
чтобы поставить 1000 нажмите 4
```

И дальше это продолжается как замкнутый круг. Извиняюсь если вопрос задан некорректно! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: у вас input за пределами цикла, если вы ввели неправильное число,то  с ним бесконечно и крутитесьэ

Comment: @splash58 Спасибо.Исправил. Но тут появилась другая проблема. Когда я ввожу неправильное число, программа выводит предупреждение и снова просит ввести корректное число. Пока все нормально, но когда я ввожу корректное число, программа выводит результат и вместо того, чтобы завершиться снова выполняет цикл while заново и только потом когда я снова ввожу корректное число программа завершается.

Comment: Разве не нужен выход из цикла в случае `else`?

Comment: В том то и дело, что программа выходит из цикла запуская функцию main, а функция main потом выполняет цикл снова. Здесь нет ошибки. Да и вообще идея была такой, чобы программа не завершалась если будет ошибка (не та буква или не та цифра)

Comment: @Nariman подставьте исправленный код в вопрос

Comment: Вы рекурсивно вызываете функцию main, когда условие попадает в else, оно запускает еще одну копию функции, и, если эта копия завершила свою работу, то вы входите в новый цикл "внешней" функции main

Comment: решением будет поставить break после main() в else

Comment: ^ Верно . Просто удалите вызов main в функции

Comment: ^ В случае splash58, нужно будет еще z = ... перенести в начало блока цикла

Comment: @Shailum Спасибо! Теперь я понял в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так

```
def main():
   bets = { 1: 100, 2:200, 3:500, 4:1000}
   while True:
      try:
         z = int(input('введите число для ставки\nчтобы поставить 100 нажмите 1\nчтобы поставить 200 нажмите 2\nчтобы поставить 500 нажмите 3\nчтобы поставить 1000 нажмите 4\n'))

         if z in bets:
            bet = bjack.bet(bets[z])
            print('\nваша ставка',cash - bet,'(ваш счет -',bet,')')
            break
         else:
            print('\nВы ввели неизвестное число,\nхотя ожидалось одно из следующих цифр: 1,2,3,4\n')
      except ValueError:
         print('\nОшибка! Вы ввели букву вместо цифры!\n')
main()
```

Comment: да, а в else желательно чтобы был вызов main для рекурсии и break чтобы else не создавала копию функции main

Comment: у вас же там вечный цикл, зачем вам рекурсивный вызов. После else вы опять спросите число

Comment: в этом и заключается смысл - спрашивать пока пользователь не введет верное число

Comment: запустите мой код и попробуйте что происходит при неверном числе:)

Comment: Все работает))) Я был невнимателен. Спасибо)))